# Find the radius of convergence of the power series and its open interval of convergence I

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty{n!\over n^n}(2x-1)^n$$

How do we approach this question? I tried to use the ratio test and ended up with $|2x-1|$ times infinity...

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please type your questions when at all possible instead of posting images.  Images can't be browsed, and aren't accessible to those using screen readers.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: I think you should have gotten $|2x-1|/e$

Comment: Try the ratio test again.  It gives (in the first step)
$$\frac{(n+1)!}{n!} \cdot \frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}} \cdot |2x-1|$$
I think you made a mistake simplifying the second factor.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use sterlings formula for factorials:

$n! \sim \sqrt{2\pi n} \cdot (\frac{n}{e})^n$

Comment: It's easier than that, if you simplify the fraction.